# How to ignore change of an attribute in block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I'm deploying web apps in Azure and I'd like to ignore changes to *scm_type* attribute within *site_config* block.

During deployment the *scm_type* attribute set to *None* and later we are changing it to something different in Azure Portal.

My current TF code looks like this:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "web_app" {
  count               = length(var.app_names)
  name                = var.app_names[count.index]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.app_resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.app_resource_group.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.app_plan.id
  tags                = var.tags
  app_settings        = var.app_settings[count.index]

  site_config {
    always_on                 = true
    websockets_enabled        = var.websockets_enabled[count.index]
    use_32_bit_worker_process = var.use_32_bit_worker_process
    scm_type                  = "None"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      site_config.0.scm_type
    ]
  }
}
```

I expect terraform plan to ignore changes in *scm_type* during infrastructure updates, but it's trying to revert it back to *None*. Line from **terraform plan** output:

`~ scm_type                  = "BitbucketGit" -> "None"`

Comment: Worth noting there are a couple bugs around this for 0.12: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21433 and https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21421 (supposed to be fixed in https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/21788).

Answer (score 49):

I think you need to fix your syntax in the ignore changes. It should look like this, or at least from what I have been able to get to work.

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
        site_config["scm_type"],
    ]
}
```

Here are the docs that have the syntax.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes

Comment: FYI: This format is currently making terraform ignore the whole site_config block for me when using v.1.1.5

Answer (score 16):

It was a terraform bug: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21433
My syntax is correct, in version 0.12.4 it's working again.

Comment: I was surprised to find that your syntax was correct, as it doesn't appear to be documented anywhere!  But FWIW to future answer-seekers - apparently blocks within a resource definition are referenced as lists (presumably to support the case where the same block appears more than once), and therefore do require this kind of numerically-indexed syntax in order to reference a nested key: `block_name[0].nested_key`

Comment: [This is the correct syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57040569/542251), not the above

Comment: The syntax in the above linked comment did not work for me, but the one in the comment from @mltsy did. Here's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24719#issuecomment-628264278) that also shows this syntax being used.

Comment: The suggested syntax of site_config["scm_type"] causes terraform to ignore the whole site_config block for me with version 1.1.5
It does indeed ignore the settings, but you also end up ignoring settings like ip_restrictions so use with caution.

Comment: @M_dk we found the same, you try ignore a particular setting in site_config, but ignores the whole site_config, have you found out a way to work around it?

Comment: @RogerChen Yes. We found that site_config[0].scm_type did the trick.
So a block like this

Comment: lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = [
    site_config[0].scm_type,
    ]
}

Comment: Can anyone comment on this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76286528/how-to-prevent-azure-apim-primary-key-not-change/76288125#76288125

Answer (score 2):

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
        site_config["scm_type"]
    ]
}
```

here `site_config["scm_type"]`

without comma(,) also it will work

Here are the docs that have the syntax.

https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-resource-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

It seems that syntax changed. M_dk confirmed that `site_config["scm_type"]` doesn't work in terraform `1.1.5`. And it is the same in version `1.3.9`. What is even worse it doesn't throw error.

**It ignores whole `site_config`**, what effectively blocks changing the site.

For version `1.1.5` and above proper syntax is:

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
        site_config[0].scm_type
    ]
}
```