# How to prevent Azure APIM Primary key not change

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I am deploying my azure apim terraform code for Azure APIM.

```
  resource "azurerm_api_management_subscription" "test" {
  api_management_name = upper("${lower(local.apim_name)}")
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  user_id             = azurerm_api_management_user.test.id
  product_id          = data.azurerm_api_management_product.crm.id
  display_name        = "testCRM"
  state               = "active"
  primary_key         = var.crm_subscription_key
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_api_management_user.test,
    module.api_product_xxx
  ]
}
```

```
variable "crm_subscription_key" {
  default     = "somevalue"
  sensitive   = true
}
```

The intention behind giving manually primary key is, It should not change the existing key.
but always it getting changed.

Can anyone provide the solution.

Comment: Please add variable definition to the question. How are you assigning the value to the varialbe?

Comment: @MarkoE, I have mentioned the variable assignment code as well

Comment: Ok, so are you re-assigning value of the variable at any point? Also, there is not much point of having the variable set to sensitive, because it will be in the state file any way.

Comment: @MarkoE, No I am not assigning the value anywhere else. Actually I need to use the default value only. not the apim generated one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_subscription" "example" {
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.example.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_api_management.example.resource_group_name
  user_id             = data.azurerm_api_management_user.example.id
  product_id          = data.azurerm_api_management_product.example.id
  display_name        = "Parser API"
  state                = "active"
  primary_key          = var.subscription_key
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_api_management_user.xxx,
   
  ]
}
```

***Here while creating the variable subscription_key , mark it **`sensitive`** so that it is protected as such and not exposed anywhere.***

```
variable "subscription_key" {
  type = string
  default = "3xxxxxxxxf"
  sensitive = true
}
```

and this value even can be stored in **`keyvault`** to reference as it is secure way and use life cycle to prevent destroy, as everytime when terraform is applied , the key won’t be destroyed and regenerated

```
lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
```

Note: ***But this applies to whole resource***

***so  specify primary_key within the ignore_changes list, which ignore changes only to the primary key and will not try  to destroy during changes to configuration.***

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "org" {
  name                       = "kkkkexamplekeyvault"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "premium"
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "Create",
      "Delete",
      "List",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "UnwrapKey",
      "WrapKey",
      "List"
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Get",
  "List",
  "Set",
  "Delete",
  "Recover",
  "Restore",
]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "org" {
  name         = "subsckey"
  value        = "xxxx"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.org.id
  
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_subscription" "example" {
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  
  display_name        = "exampleapi"
  state                = "active"
 // primary_key          = var.subscription_key
  primary_key=    azurerm_key_vault_secret.org.value 
lifecycle {
   // prevent_destroy = true
    ignore_changes = [
      primary_key
    ]
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_api_management_user.zxc,
  ]
}
```

[image]

**Reference** : [How to ignore change of an attribute in block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992065/how-to-ignore-change-of-an-attribute-in-block) -StackOverflow

Comment: even using after this code     , Its generating new subscription key                                                                                
primary_key=    azurerm_key_vault_secret.org.value 
lifecycle {
   // prevent_destroy = true
    ignore_changes = [
      primary_key
    ]
  }